# React component not rendering, page shows but is blank

Tags: reactjs, twilio

I followed a tutorial to build audio drop in chat rooms using Django and leveraging the Twilio Programmable Voice API.

In a nutshell, there is a form that currently appears in all pages. This is a simple one field form with a submit button. Through this form I enter my nickname (the name of the room). This is then sent to my server which would be exposed to Twilio through a url I get from ngrok. I send this nickname to the appropriate API endpoint and get a token from Twilio. I set the token to my state along with the device type I am using. I then use `history.push()` to move to another page: `/rooms`. My pages routing will check whether I have a valid Twilio token in state, if I do; I would render my `RoomsList` component. Which should have the header 'Available Rooms' and a list of all rooms that have been created.

I am trying to remove the signup form and instead enable a user to click a button, in this instance `Start Coding`. I would then send the username to Twilio (as the nickname), receive a token and redirect to `RoomsList`.

However, when I try to do this (replicate the functions I have connected with signupform), when I redirect to `/rooms` I get a blank page instead of rendering `RoomsList`. I have console logged each step; I am getting a username, a valid TwilioToken and device type. However, for some reason `RoomsList` does not render - I do not receive any error messages to help me debug..

Here's my code

Button to send user name

```
const { retrieveChallenge, navToRooms } = useContext(AuthContext)
...
<button className="button button-primary button-wide-mobile button-sm"
    onClick={navToRooms}
    > Start Coding
</button>
```

NavToRooms Function inside AuthContext:

```
const navToRooms = () => {
    const roomName = user.username
    setupTwilio(roomName);
    console.log('twilio token is', state.twilioToken)
    history.push('/rooms');
}
```

setupTwilio:

```
const setupTwilio = (roomName) => {
        fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/voice_chat/token/${roomName}`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            const twilioToken = data.token;
            const device = new Device(twilioToken);
            device.updateOptions(twilioToken, {
                codecPreferences: ['opus', 'pcmu'],
                fakeLocalDTMF: true,
                maxAverageBitrate: 16000
            });
            device.on('error', (device) => {
                console.log("error: ", device)
            });
            setState((state) => {
                return {...state, device, twilioToken}
            });
            console.log('we are inside setup Twilio')
        })
        ...
    };
```

My router:

```
const Pages = () => {
  const [ state ] = useGlobalState();
  const room = state.selectedRoom;

  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path={'/rooms/:roomId'}>
            {room?<Room room={room}/> : null}
        </Route>
        <Route path='/rooms'>
           <RoomList/>
          {state.twilioToken? <RoomList /> : <SignupForm />}
        </Route>
        <Route path='/'>
          <SignupForm />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

In the above, I added `<RoomsList/>` above state.TwilioToken just to see if RoomsList would be rendered if I didn't check if I have a TwilioToken in state first.

which is connected to my main router:

```
<AuthProvider>
    <Header/>
    ...
    <AppRoute exact path="/timer" component={Timer} />
    <RoomContextProvider>
        <div>
            <Pages />
        </div>
    </RoomContextProvider>
    ...
</AuthProvider>
```

Here's my RoomsList Component:

```
const RoomList = () =>  {
    const [state, setState] = useGlobalState();
    const fetchRooms = useFetchRooms('/rooms');
    useEffect(() => {
        fetchRooms().then(rooms => {
            setState((state) => {
                return {...state, rooms};
            });
        })
    }, [fetchRooms, setState]);
    console.log('we are getting inside RoomList')

    return (
            <div>
                <h1>Available rooms</h1>

                { state.rooms.length > 0?
                    <ul>
                        {state.rooms.map((selectedRoom, index) => (
                        <li key={index + 1}>
                            <Link to={`/rooms/${index + 1}`} onClick={() => {setState({...state, selectedRoom})}}>{selectedRoom.room_name}</Link>
                        </li>
                        ))}
                    </ul>: <div>Create a new room to get started</div>}
                <NewRoom />
            </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: Can we take a look at your `rooms` component?

Comment: @Enfieldli Did you mean RoomsList, I have added that to the question

Comment: which version of React-router-dom do you have?

Comment: @EisaRezaei  "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",

Answer (score 0):

In the blog post, the call to `useFetchRooms` uses the URL `/api/rooms` but you are using the URL `/rooms`. My guess is that the `fetch` call is failing because `/rooms` is a route in your front-end and if you switch that out for `/api/rooms` it might just work (or at least get you a bit further).

```
const RoomList = () =>  {
    const [state, setState] = useGlobalState();
    const fetchRooms = useFetchRooms('/rooms'); // <-----
```